# Reading tables with strings containing the separator in R

Tags: r, separator

I got a text file with data I want to read, but one of the columns is a messy "code" which contains the same character used as the separator. Take the following set as an example:

```
number:string
1:abc?][
2:def:{+
```

There will be a line with 3 columns and only 2 column names.
Is there any strategy to read this dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Read the file a line at a time, split into two parts on the ":", bind into a data frame. The column names get lost but you can put them back on again easy enough. You need the `stringr` and `readr` packages:

```
> do.call(rbind.data.frame,stringr::str_split(readr::read_lines("seps.csv",skip=1),":",2))
  c..1....2.. c..abc.......def.....
1           1                abc?][
2           2                def:{+
```

Here with `stringr` and `readr` attached for readability, with the names fixed:

```
> library(stringr)
> library(readr)
> d = do.call(rbind.data.frame,str_split(read_lines("seps.csv",skip=1),":",2))
> names(d) = str_split(read_lines("seps.csv",n_max=1),":",2)[[1]]
> d
  number string
1      1 abc?][
2      2 def:{+
```

Answer (score 0):

Good old `regular expressions` should help you with this

### Read txt file

```
df <- read.table("pathToFile/fileName.txt", header = TRUE)
```

The `data.frame` will be one column, so we will need to split it based on some pattern

### Create the columns

```
df$number <- sub("([0-9]+):.*", "\\1", df[, 1])
df$string <- sub("[0-9]+:(.*)", "\\1", df[, 1])

df <- df[, c("number", "string")]
View(df)
```